# Image Gallery tutorial is deprecated

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling with this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

it wont work on API greater then 1.6, and i can't make it work.
the "R.styleable" is deprecated

i would be grateful if anyone can provide a working tutorial for an image gallery.

Thanks!

Comment: You will find an answer:
[Here!](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg11862.html)

Comment: I used this once and it worked perfectly, they explain very well. I hope this helps.
http://galleria.io/

Answer (score 7):

Not only the tutorial is deprecated, the whole widget is deprecated since Jelly Bean.

Google's suggestion: use ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView instead and don't use it other scroll views like ListView. Conclusion: Help yourself... :/

SNow it's your task to implement the center-locked swipe behavior of the gallery and using a BaseAdapter to preload and show adjacent items. Some UI patterns like horizontal galleries in  vertical scroll views (often used in news apps) are harder to implement.

The problem with the view pager: it tooks the whole height of the parent view container and ignores the height's of it's children. So it's hard to layout one or more view pagers in a vertical scroll view or as a list view item.

Answer (score 1):

R.styleable doesn't refer to anything which core android package offers.
It is referring to style that your project is defining for android gallery item background.

in the example that is given at the URL

Did you follow this ?

Create a new XML file in the res/values/ directory named attrs.xml. Insert the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```